# Predicting the cost of a Snowflake query before executing it

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to predict the cost of a query I'm going to execute on Snowflake before actually executing it? We would like to avoid high costs, so having the cost calculated after executing the query doesn't help much.

Other technologies such as BigQuery provide calculators to estimate the query's cost before executing, but I didn't find such an option for Snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a tool within Snowflake that will do this for you automatically unfortunately, you'd have to manually figure it out yourself.

For example, a naive way of calculating it could be: run the query on a [10% sample of the table(s)](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html) and then take the credit usage of that query and multiply it by 10.